# How do I add a foreign key to a Table in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created two tables called TermTable and CourseTable. I want CourseTable to have a foreign key to reference TermTable.

This is the code where I create the tables:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.END_DATE +
                ")"
        );
//I want to give CourseTable a foreign key to reference TermTable^^
        db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.END_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.COURSE_STATUS + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.OPTIONAL_NOTE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_NAME + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_PHONE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_EMAIL +

                ")"
        );
}
```

This is the code Schema code:

```
public class TermDbSchema {

public static final class TermTable {
        public static final String NAME = "terms";
        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String START_DATE = "startdate";
            public static final String END_DATE = "enddate";
        }
    }
    public static final class CourseTable {
        public static final String NAME = "courses";
        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String START_DATE = "startdate";
            public static final String END_DATE = "enddate";
            public static final String COURSE_STATUS = "coursestatus";
            public static final String OPTIONAL_NOTE = "optionalnote";
            public static final String MENTOR_NAME = "mentorname";
            public static final String MENTOR_PHONE = "mentorphone";
            public static final String MENTOR_EMAIL = "mentoremail";        
        }
}
```

How do I add a foreign key to CourseTable so that it can reference TermTable?

Comment: See the `CREATE TABLE` syntax, including how to mark column(s) as foreign keys, here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Also described, with examples, here: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CourseTable to have another column for the reference *(link, relationship, association, mapping are all other terms)* :-

```
public static final class CourseTable {
    public static final String NAME = "courses";
    public static final class Cols {
        public static final String UUID = "uuid";
        public static final String TITLE = "title";
        public static final String START_DATE = "startdate";
        public static final String END_DATE = "enddate";
        public static final String COURSE_STATUS = "coursestatus";
        public static final String OPTIONAL_NOTE = "optionalnote";
        public static final String MENTOR_NAME = "mentorname";
        public static final String MENTOR_PHONE = "mentorphone";
        public static final String MENTOR_EMAIL = "mentoremail"; 
        public static final String TERM_LINK = "termlink"    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED   
    }
```

- the column name could of course be what you wish

Change the Creating SQL for the courses table to add the Foreign Key constraint.

```
         db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.NAME + "(" +
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.END_DATE + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.COURSE_STATUS + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.OPTIONAL_NOTE + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_NAME + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_PHONE + ", " +
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_EMAIL + ", " + //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
            TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TERM_LINK + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(_id)" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED

            ")"
    );
```

- you may wish to adhere to your convetions an omit INTEGER (the type affinity of the column), that would not be an issue. It has been included because most would specifiy column types rather than have the default (NUMERIC) applied.

#### Important

Then override the **onConfigure** to call the **[setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean))** passing true.

e.g. :-

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

- **By default Foreign Key Support is turned off, making the above coding changes will be useless unless Foreign Key Support is turned on.**

You will need to then do 1 of the following :-

- Delete the App's data
- Uninstall the App

and then rerun the App.

- **Note** any existing data will be lost. If you need to retain data then that could be relatively complicated.

## Foreign Keys

Note that defining a foreign key is ONLY defining a constraint (rule) that requires the value being placed into the column that has the constraint to be a value in one of the rows of the parent table/column that is referenced.

Defining a Foreign Key constraint DOES NOT automatically make relationships happen. That is you will still have to determine the related term when adding a course (a common misconception is that it does this).

You may wish to consider extending the definition to include ON DELETE and ON UPDATE actions, such as CASCADE. e.g. ON DELETE CASCADE would, when a(if) term row is deleted, deleted the child rows in the course table. Likewise ON UPDATE CASCADE will update the referenced value of the children in the course table should that value be changed in the term table (these can make life simpler).

e.g. you could use :-

```
    TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TERM_LINK + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
```

You may wish to refer to [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Define a string inside class `Cols` of class `CourseTable` which will hold the name of this new column like:

```
public static final String TERM_ID = "term_id";
```

Change the `CREATE` statement of the table `CourseTable`:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.NAME + "(" +
        "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.END_DATE + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.COURSE_STATUS + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.OPTIONAL_NOTE + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_NAME + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_PHONE + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_EMAIL + ", " +
        TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TERM_ID + " INTEGER, " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TERM_ID +
        ") REFERENCES " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(_id)" + 
        ")"
);
```

This new column will reference the column `_id` which is the PRIMARY KEY of `TermTable`. 
You need to uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and then rerun to recreate the database.

Comment: this not good  setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true) of get database open or onConfigure is in need elsewise nothing does happening.